# $\frac{d(v^2)}{dx} = \frac{d((dx/dt)^2)}{dx}$ Derivative of Velocity Squared with respect to Position

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

$$\frac{d(v^2)}{dx} = d\frac{((dx/dt)^2)}{dx}$$

Physically it makes sense - how does velocity squared change with respect to its position.

What would the analytical solution be?

$$\frac{d((dx/dt)^2)}{dx} = \frac{dx}{dt}\,d\frac{(dx/dt)}{dx} = ?$$

Comment: Actually, that relates work done with kinetic energy.  For your interest, see another answer [**here**](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310064/question-about-a-v-mathrm-dv-mathrm-dx/310072#310072)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the chain rule gives

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dv^2}{dx}&=\frac{dv^2}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}\\\\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{\frac{dv^2}{dt}}}{\color{red}{\frac{dx}{dt}}}\\\\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{2v\frac{dv}{dt}}}{\color{red}{v}}\\\\
&=2a 
\end{align}$$

where $a=\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ is the acceleration.